# Excel - VBA - Selecting Data in the columns

Tags: vba, excel

WE have a code to clean and then copy excel data into a tab, where it accumulates. 
Columns A:H.

We need this data to have month in the next column (I). 
For all the new lines, meaning in the range (Ix:Ix) where the length is from last row of column I to last row of the newly pasted data.

The Code is below:

```
Sub Trial_Fix()

' Trial_Fix Macro
Dim LastRow As Long

' Deleting columns and adding columns of the raw data.
    Sheets("FP Data dump").Select
    Range("A:I,K:R,V:W").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("CF Data Dump").Select
    Range("A:C,E:E,H:H,J:J,M:O,Q:S,G:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Fuel Data Dump").Select
    Range("A:C,E:G,I:J,N:O,Q:Q,S:AC").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select

' Pasting CF Data

' Pasting FP + Data


' Pasting Fuel Data
    Sheets("Fuel Data Dump").Select
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:H" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CLEAN FUEL DATA").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: First things first - [Avoid Select](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/445425)

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to work with [.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx), [.Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) and the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property, the following is all you require directly under the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) command.

```
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   With Selection
       With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, .Columns.Count)
           .Value = Date
           .NumberFormat = "mmmm"
       End With
   End With
```

However, using the methods and properties mentioned above is unreliable at best and evenly potentially capable of obfuscating your data. Consider the following rewrite that uses explicit referencing to address [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and [Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) objects.

```
Sub Trial_Fix()
    ' Trial_Fix Macro
    Dim lrs As Long, lrd As Long
    Dim wsCFD As Worksheet

    With Worksheets("FP Data dump")
        .Range("A:I,K:R,V:W").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("C:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        ' Pasting FP + Data
        '?????????????

    End With

    With Worksheets("CF Data Dump")
        .Range("A:C,E:G,I:J,N:O,Q:Q,S:AC").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        ' Pasting CF Data
        '?????????????

    End With

    Set wsCFD = Worksheets("CLEAN FUEL DATA")
    With Worksheets("Fuel Data Dump")
        'get rid of unwanted columns
        .Range("A:C,E:E,G:H,J:J,M:O,Q:S").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        'last populated row in source
        lrs = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'first blank cell in destination
        lrd = wsCFD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        'direct value transfer is faster than copy/paste values and does not involve the clip board
        With .Range("A1:H" & lrs)
            wsCFD.Cells(lrd, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            wsCFD.Cells(lrd, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, .Columns.Count) = Date
            wsCFD.Cells(lrd, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, .Columns.Count).NumberFormat = "mmmm"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The above uses the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to reference [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) worksheets. Anything inside the With ... End With gets its inherited parent reference by adding a period (aka *full stop* or `.`) as a prefix to each [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).